# Ruby Array of hash, and map function

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have an array of hashes, like this:

```
my_array = [{foo:1,bar:"hello",baz:3},{foo:2,bar:"hello2",baz:495,foo_baz:"some_string"},...] 
#there can be arbitrary many in this list.
#There can also be arbitrary many keys on the hashes.
```

I want to create a new array that is a copy of the last array, except that I remove any `:bar` entries.

```
my_array2 = [{foo:1,baz:3},{foo:2,baz:495,foo_baz:"some_string"},...]
```

I can get the `my_array2` by doing this:

```
my_array2 = my_array.map{|h| h.delete(:bar)}
```

However, this changes the original `my_array`, which I want to stay the same.

Is there a way of doing this without having to duplicate my_array first?

Comment: are you using active_support?

Comment: Just a note: duplicating an array wouldn't help :)

Comment: @BroiSatse I found that out actually.

Comment: @Cort3z - Just one more note: You will end up with a new array with new hashes regardless of whether you use dup or not. Those are however a shallow copies, so they won't use too much additional memory.

Comment: Yeah, they should be reference only, which is ok for me. The reason why I don't want to do deep copy is that the stuff in my hash is potentially very big (strings of length 1000+).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

one of many ways to accomplish this:

```
my_array2 = my_array.map{|h| h.reject{|k,v| k == :bar}}
```

Comment: beat me by 21 secs :)

Comment: I would say [Hash#reject](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-reject) is purpose-built for this.  One tiny detail: I would make `reject`'s block variables `|k,_|` to emphasize the fact you are only using the key (as I see @Santosh has done).

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Two small questions: Why is `reject` better than `select`? Is it faster, or is it simply readability? And: same question for the `_`. Faster or just pretty?

Comment: Sorry for misleading you, Cortt3z.  `reject` and `select` are more-or-less equivalent here, as both must check all the elements.  I was poking fun at @Santosh, suggesting he chose `select` only because Philipp had used `reject`.

Comment: Ahh.. hehe, get it. Funny that I `selected` the `reject` ^^ But really tough, the `_`. I remember reading something about that a long time ago. Is it faster, or just pretty? I would guess it is a bit faster if it does not have to allocate any variables for each element.

Comment: @CarySwoveland just to be clear, Philipp's answer was not there when I was typing mine. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
my_array.map {|h| h.select{|k, _| k != :bar} }
# => [{:foo=>1, :baz=>3}, {:foo=>2, :baz=>495, :foo_baz=>"some_string"}]
```

Comment: I would say 21 seconds counts as a tie.  +1 for both of you.  `reject` is so much better though. :-)